# ros sick lms parameters help please

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a SICK LMS 200 hooked up and am using ROS with the sicktoolbox and sicktoolbox_wrapper.

my question relates to the parameters found on this page...http://ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox_wrapper#Nodes

i have tried changing parameters such as angle (to 10 for example) or resolution but the readouts shown by rostopic echo /scan always give me a large amount of read outs.

is it not possible to change the parameters to get, for example, only 10 values at a specified angle range?

i can understand that the actual mechanics inside the laser might not allow this but then why are these parameters offered? is it not possible to change them at all?
the baud is able to be changed but what about Hz?

and when changing the parameters i have tried both these methods with no success:
rosparam set sicklms/angle 5
OR
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:= /dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:= 500000 _angle:= 10 _resolution:= 1

thanks for any tips!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27979/ros-sick-lms-parameters-help-please/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Angle and resolution are forwarded to the underlying driver. Some SICK scanners have different angles or resolutions that they can scan in. For example, some may have a 180 degree field of view with 1 degree angular resolution and a 90 degree field of view with a 0.25 degree angular resolution. Those parameters allow the driver to reconfigure the scanner into one of its supported modes.

Note that these have to be a supported mode - you can't just pick a 10 degree field of view unless the scanner itself supports such a mode.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2012-02-21**:
thanks for the answer. tech specs of the LMS200-30106 (that we use) show the actual device does support 0.25, 0.5 and 1 degree of resolution. 0.25 res will limit the scan angle to 100 degrees though. so my question is really if the ros lms drivers found in sicktoolbox (and wrapper) are supported?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-21**:
I'm honestly not certain if it's supported. Try it with an angle of 100 degrees and a resolution of 0.25 degrees and what sort of scans you get, i.e. make sure that the sensor_msgs/LaserScan parameters match your config and that you have ~400 measurements and that they look good in RVIZ.